# apache web server hosting issue

Tags: apache

i have hosted my website on a folder in my root.

```
/mywebsitedir/
```

and defined an alias in my apache conf file.

```
 # Alias for mywebsite

Alias /myalias/mywebsitedir

<Directory /mywebsitedir>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

now when i make request on my server.

when i make any request on my server, as my server is hosting many other site.

```
www.site1.com/myalias

www.site2.com/myalias

www.site3.com/myalias.
```

i all cases it open my website.

i want to restrict that mywebsite should be only accessible from www.site1.com/myalis
.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the Alias into a VirtualHost for the specific website. Otherwise, it becomes a global alias for all websites.